# Threading has no attribute Thread, no files named threading.py

Tags: python, multithreading, server

I'm coding a simple client/server setup. The server seems to start fine, but when I try to connect the client I get a message saying "Threading has no attribute Thread." Then the server stops.

The only suggestion I've found doesn't work for me ... I have no files named threading.py, and the `print(threading.__file__)` statement shows the correct file path for the threading module.

I've left out functions that don't use the threading module for this example.

```
import socket
import threading
print(threading.__file__)

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = "utf-8"
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

...

def start():
    # Listen for and accept connections
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        t = threading.thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        t.start()
        print(f'[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount() - 1}')

print('Server is starting ...')
start()
```

Comment: there is no  Thread mentioned in your code

Comment: you are using threading.thread but https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0ab2384c5f56625e99bb35417cadddfe24d347e1/Lib/threading.py#L871 says threading.Thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct form is `threading.Thread`, not `threading.thread`.

Otherwise, thank you for having researched first, and looked if you didn't have a `threading.py` file shadowing Python's: that is indeed the usual cause of this type of error. In this case, it is just a typo, though.

Comment: I get a message saying "Threading has no attribute Thread."

Comment: but "threading" is the module name: it is supposed to be lower case, not "Threading". And  "Thread" is capitalized because it is the class name.

Comment: shouldnt be closed as kind of spam question